# How to target a specific event registration form in an extension

Tags: extension, hooks

I'm trying to use a custom extension rather than using a template override (template_name.extra.tpl) to implement some jQuery on an event registration form (essentially to hide some form fields unless the right radio button is selected).
Jackrabbithanna's useful guide here (http://www.jackrabbithanna.com/articles/easy-jquery-modificaiton-civicrm-forms) has been most helpful in getting me much of the way.

That guidance talks about targeting a specific contribution page by using:

```
    function tctaextend_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
if($formName=='CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main'){
     if($form->_id==2 ){
      CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile('com.skvare.testextend', 'my_alter_contribform.js');
     }
   }
}
```

In my case I want to target a particular event. The form name is CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register, so I thought I could do a straight replacement, e.g.:

```
    function myextension_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
if($formName=='CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register'){
     if($form->_id==1 ){
      CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addScriptFile('com.example.myextension', 'my_alter_eventform.js');
     }
   }
}
```

But that generates a php notice:

> Notice: Undefined property: CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register::$_id in myextension_civicrm_buildForm()

And also throws a fatal error if I try to create a new contribution page, even though the hook function is aiming to impact only event registration forms.

If I remove the line

```
 if($form->_id==1 ){
```

Then no errors, but my injected jQuery will presumably impact every event registration form rather than just the event I want to target?
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Digging into the hook reference documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/ I can see that the correct approach is

```
if ($form->_eventId == 1) {
```

Answer (score 1):

As Graham mentioned this is the correct approach:

```
if ($form->_eventId == 1) {
```

It is possible that _eventId is protected, so you can not access it directly. In that case use

```
$eventId = $form->getVar('_eventId');
if ($eventId == 1) {
```